# Como fazer slideshow rodar quando a aba "nova guia" está aberta?

Tags: jquery, plugin, google-chrome-extensão, slide

Estou tentando fazer um script de slideshow rodar toda vez que uma nova guia é aberta no Google Chrome.
Preciso fazer a seguinte execução:

1-Fazer um script de slideshow rodar 10 imagens [aqui coloco apenas 3], em fade, toda vez que o usuário abrir uma nova guia.

Problemas:

1-O script é carregado, mas o slideshow "não acontece";

2-Das 10 imagens, apenas a ultima é exibida [como no "theme" padrão];

Já li a documentação, mas não encontrei solução;

Já usei vários plugins, mas o resultado é o mesmo.

Uso o [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript),mas sem sucesso;

Estou usando [slidesjs](http://www.slidesjs.com/).

Alguém pode dá uma ajuda,please ?

Isso já está me dando nos nervos!

html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>New Tabe</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <!--<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

  <!-- font awesome -->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">-->

  <!-- custom style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/core.css">


  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="bs-slide-show">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/sports" alt="" class="img-responsive">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="" class="img-responsive">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="" class="img-responsive">

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- jquery circle plugin-->
  <!--<script src="assets/js/lib/jquery.cycle.lite.js"></script>-->
  <script src="assets/js/lib/source/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

core.css

```css
.bs-slide-show {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

newtab.js

```
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(
null,
{file: "main.js" }
```

);

main.js

```
$(function(){
$(".bs-slide-show").slidesjs({

    navigation:{
        active: false

    },
    pagination:{
        active: false,
    },
    effect:{
        slide: {
            speed: 200
        },
        fade:{
            speed: 300,
            crossfade: true
        }
    }
});
```

});

manifest.json

```js
{ 
"version": "2015.12.0.1", 
"name": "__MSG_NAME__",
"description": "__MSG_EXT_DESC__",
"default_locale": "en",
  
"permissions" : [
   "management",
   "tabs",
   "notifications"
],

"chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "newtabe.html"
 },

 "options_page": "docs/options.html",
  
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {               
     "19": "assets/img/icons/icon-19.png",          
     "38": "assets/img/icons/icon-38.png"          
   },
   "default_title": "__MSG_DEFAUL_TITLE",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"        
 },

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["newtabe.js, main.js, jquery.js"],
    "persistent": false
 },   
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

OBs:
As imagens são carregadas;

Consegui fazer o override da nova guia, trocando-a pela minha;

A extensão carrega os arquivos normalmente;